# Was Alfred one of the people who trained Batman?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

In the comics, did Alfred train Bruce Wayne to fight before he left to train around the world like he did in the Gotham TV series?

Comment: In *which* comics? Batman has had more origin stories than I've had hot dinners

Comment: Heck, [he was pretty incompetent](https://nypost.com/2014/11/11/batmans-loyal-servant-alfred-follows-a-long-line-of-guises/) for the first few decades, and just a butler for the next few.

Answer (score 2):

Depends which continuity we're talking.

In the main comic continuity, Alfred doesn't train Bruce Wayne. Alfred [was a British spy in WWII](https://www.cbr.com/batman-alfred-pennyworth-spy-world-war-ii-debut/), but we never see him train Bruce Wayne (mainly because espionage isn't exactly a Batman skill). Generally, Bruce Wayne would be trained by [a myriad of other people](https://www.dc.com/blog/2022/01/20/becoming-the-knight-bruce-waynes-mentors-on-the-path-to-batman). Most other continuities have kept to some version of this story, including people like Zatara (father of Zatanna), Ra's Al Ghul, various detectives, etc.

Alfred might be in [some lists](https://www.cbr.com/dc-comics-batman-characters-who-trained-bruce-wayne/), but not in the purest "Batman training" sense (i.e. training him to do the spectacular things he does). Alfred is someone who is often seen chastising Bruce Wayne for neglecting Bruce Wayne

> If not for Alfred, Bruce might not be so keen on keeping up his appearances as Gotham's number one playboy, and instead showcasing himself around as the dark and brooding superhero that stalks the criminals of Gotham.

He is also often shown as the one patching Batman and his compatriots up.

Some continuities do give Alfred a more active role. [Beware the Batman](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Beware_the_Batman) has their Alfred [doing a lot of Batman training](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Alfred_Pennyworth_(Beware_the_Batman))

> As Bruce grew, Alfred trained him in criminology, computer hacking, forensics and martial arts, preparing Bruce for his future as Batman. After Bruce took on the life of a costumed crime fighter, Alfred took on the role of a friend and confidante to his employer, helping track down leads and examine evidence from the Batcave while Bruce worked in the field.

Comment: Alfred was also Bruce's primary trainer in the TV show Gotham.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis It does, but the question already mentions that and wants similar stories.